# Assigning unassigned string to array

Tags: c#

I've got a function which takes a ArrayList and loads it with strings along the line of

```
void func( ref ArrayList data )
{
    if( data[0].GetType() == typeof(String) )
        data[0] = "Jimmy";
}
```

In the function that calls func() I am having to create strings to put in the array:

```
ArrayList data = new ArrayList(1);
string str = "";
data.Add(str);
```

Is it possible to give the ArrayList the object types without having to create an object of that type? This:

```
ArrayList data = new ArrayList(1);
string str;
data.Add(str);
```

Gives a "Use of unassigned local variable 'str'" error.

@James and Guffa: Thanks for the 'stylistic' hints, I'm new to c# and the advice is much appreciated

Comment: It is less verbose to use `is` rather than `GetType() == typeof(String).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. What you want is a reference that points to a string, and that is only possible if it actually points to a string. The fact that the variable that holds the reference is declared as a string reference doesn't matter once you have copied the reference from the variable to the list.

I think that you should rethink the entire concept. I don't know your reason for sending in a list of values and replace them like that, but there has to be a more object oriented way of doing it.

The `ArrayList` class is practically obsolete, you should use a generic `List<T>` instead (even if you can't find any other common base class than `object`).

As you are always sending in a list object to the method and not replacing it with a new list object, you should not use the `ref` keyword. That's only for when you want to change the reference to the list, not the contents of the list.

Comment: Cheers Guffa. I'm doing it this way as func extracts data from a comms link but each message has different data types in different orders. The ArrayList seemed like a good way of telling func what data types were where.

Answer (score 0):

You can send two parameters, one ref ArrayList in which members will be assigned and the other an ArrayList and the called function can assign at indexes in data where the type is String

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting to keep this type safe then could you not use a `List<T>` class here instead e.g. `List<string>`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do in your method with the above code is to call `GetType()` on `null`, which is not possible.

Why not use a generic list `List<string>` in this case? You can elegantly skip the part of using `GetType()` to determine the type with this approach:

```
static void func(List<string> data)
{
    if(data.Count > 0)
        data[0] = "Jimmy";
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>(1);

    string str = "";

    lst.Add(str);

    func(lst);

    System.Console.WriteLine(lst[0]); //Prints out 'Jimmy'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not a perfect question, the list contains different data types